# Solutions to second order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a second order differential equation such as $y''-y = 0$.  Suppose we are told that $y_1= e^x$ and $y_2=e^{-x}$ satisfy the DE.  Hence, $y=c_1e^x + c_2e^{-x}$ also satisfies the DE.  Do we know that all solutions of this DE are of this form?

Comment: Please add your own thoughts about this. At the moment it is not clear what *your* question is about this task. What do you know, what do you consider non-trivial,...

Comment: @LutzL I added a comment to Jan’s answer.

Answer (score 2):

You still have to check that your solutions are linearly independent. Therefore, you can use the Wronski - determinant

$$W(y_1, y_2) = \begin{vmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1' & y_2' \end{vmatrix}.$$

Show, that $W(y_1, y_2) \neq 0$.

Comment: how does this prove that every solution to the DE is of the form above?  The wronskian just gives us linear independence.  If we could show the solution space is two dimensional then we are done by the Wronskian argument.

Comment: This is a well-known fact in the theory of linear ODEs. If you want to proof it, you probably need the existence and uniqueness theorem together with the linearity.

Answer (score 0):

In any other initial value problem you can construct from its solution $z$ the linear combination 
$$
z(t)=y(t)-y(t_0)\cosh(t-t_0)-y'(t_0)\sinh(t-t_0)
$$
Then $z(t_0)=0$ and $z'(t_0)=0$, so that by the uniqueness theorem $z=0$ everywhere, and thus
$$
y(t)=y(t_0)\cosh(t-t_0)+y'(t_0)\sinh(t-t_0).
$$